# JavaScript Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: plusSlides is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make a slideshow (both with arrows and with bullets and with time - I was inspired by w3) and the first time I got an error "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at slideshow ERROR". I did some research so I added DOM to the script.js file, but I got another error.

This is the code in HTML(I have reduced it to only the essential):

```
<html lang="ro-RO">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
            
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
            <img src="(1).jpg" width="395px" height="687px">    
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
            <img src="(2).jpg" width="395px" height="687px">
                </div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1);">❮</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1);">❯</a>
            
    </div>
            <br>
            
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.mySlides{
    display: none;
}
.dot{
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){
    
    let slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        let i;
        let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

        if (n > slides.length) {
            slideIndex = 1;
        }

        if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = slides.length;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }

        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }


    setInterval(function() {
        plusSlides(1);
    }, 2000);

});
```

I am new to JS.

Comment: "I was inspired by w3" — W3 is an abbreviation for WWW. There are a number of websites which use it as part of their names (including the awful W3Schools).

Comment: "the first time I got an error "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at slideshow ERROR". I did some research so I added DOM to the script.js file, but I got another error." — Are you asking about the first error or the *other* error that you haven't quoted in the body of your question?

Comment: because the function is not in global scope..... Putting the functions inside of the DOMContentLoaded prevents them from being seen. Either moved them out or bind event handlers with addEventListner.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plusSlides` is only defined within the scope of the function passed to `document.addEventListener`.  But the HTML is trying to call it in global scope:

```
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1);">❮</a>
```

You can *define* the functions in global scope, then you can wait for the `DOMContentLoaded` event to *initially invoke* your functionality.  For example:

```
let slideIndex = 1;

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }

    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    setInterval(function() {
        plusSlides(1);
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this works good, Thank you!